# Close and open browser with Selenium C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, selenium, browser

I want to close and then open the browser without closing the driver of Selenium, using C#. I don't want to:

```
driver.Quit();
```

How can I close and the open again Chrome?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Closing the last instance of browser with quit or without quit will result in browser not reachable exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. close will close the lastly opened browser instance. The difference between `Close()` and `Quit()` in C# is that the `Quit()` calls `IDisposbile` internally and release all the resources used internally which will close and free up all the processes.

Coming back to your problem, if you want to reuse the same session without closing just simply call `Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:blank")`